# Symfony2 - Trouble using usort inside a controller

Tags: arrays, symfony, usort

I am trying to merge the contents of 2 arrays then use usort to get the posts with most views.

Trying to use usort to sort the contents of an array.

Am getting the follow error: 
`("Notice: Undefined property: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Article::$getViews in /.../PageController.php line 15")`

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

**Sort function inside of controller**

```
private static function popularSort($articles, $posts, $articles2, $posts2)
{
    return $articles->getViews() == $posts->getViews() ? 0 : ( $articles->getViews() < $posts->getViews()) ? 1: -1;
}
```

**Sidebar action**

```
$articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Article')
    ->getArticles();

$posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
    ->getPosts();

$popular = array_merge($articles, $posts);

usort($popular, array($this, 'popularSort'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a property called `getViews` in your `Article` class.

You probably have a property called `views` and a method `getViews` meaning you should call the actual method with the brackets like `$article->getViews()`.

Answer (score 1):

`getViews` is a getter method for accessing the property views of the Entities `Post` and `Article`. So while accessing it u should access it as `$articles->getViews()`.

But if you simply want to compare the property `views` of the two entities compare them using their property name instead of their getter

Assuming views as the name of the property, the call should be something like:

`$posts->views` and `$articles->views`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Ankit, but Qoop was first.

Comment: Actually I am now trying to add in 2 more entities to this. But am getting an error. `popularSort function--return $articles->getViews() == $posts->getViews() && $articles2->getViews() == $posts2s->getViews() ? 0 : ( $articles2->getViews() < $posts2->getViews() && $predictions->getViews() < $scorings->getViews()) ? 1: -1;` and am getting this error: `"Warning: Missing argument 3 for Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\PageController::popularSort()` Any idea?

Comment: This problem is usually caused due to inconsistency in the function definition and function call. The function that u have pasted in the above comment does not seem to calrify. I would suggest posting a new question. Or searchin for exisiting question on this site

Comment: The error is not where you have defined the function the error is where this function function is called. The function is expection more params then it is actually passed

Comment: Hmmm I have updated the array_merge to incorporate the other 2 arrays, what am I missing with the usort?

Comment: Added a new question if you can help me out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800238/symfony2-error-when-adding-2-more-arrays-to-usort